# Select multiple images from device's gallery in Hybrid application

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an application for Android I want the button in the .html file to show the device's native gallery (in my case is android) which user can select multiple images and present it's thumbnails in the html page.
I already watch the video in [This Website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en) and I still get confusing.

Thank you for all suggestion and solutions.

Ps. I found the solution of select multiple images [Here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/) but I am not sure how to use it. ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current Gallery application of Android.

Within the Gallery application, you can select multiple photos and you can share them using `SEND_MULTIPLE` `Intent`. But that is different.

When you select photo from your application, that is called PICKER. And PICKER `Intent` does not support multiple selection.